# RMI deployment in Jboss server

Tags: java, rmi

I want to deploy a RMI using the Jboss RMI(or JNDI) port 1099. Every thing is working fine when Jboss server is not in picture(i.e using main program). For deployment on server, I tried 2 approaches.
1) Getting the Jboss registry port and binding the RMI registry to that port.
Following is the code which i have written in the init method of servlet
(Here Server is my interface which extends Remote,ServerImplementor is class implementing Server)

```
    public void init() throws ServletException {
            {
            Server implementor=new ServerImplementor();
            Remote obj = UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(implementor, 0);
            Registry r=LocateRegistry.getRegistry();
            System.out.println("Registry post::"+r.REGISTRY_PORT);
            r.bind("TestRMI", obj);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

The problem with this approach is when i run the client with following code:

```
    registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("localhost",1099);
            hello = (Server) (registry.lookup("TestRMI"));
```

```
The error which i get is: java.rmi.ConnectIOException: non-JRMP server at remote endpoint

2) The 2nd approach which i tried is using JNDI, exposing a RMI(This is one approach which i came to know through googling)
Following is the code for the init method of servlet.Here the protocol used is jnp
```

```
    try {
            Server remoteObj=new ServerImplementor();
            Properties properties=new Properties();
            properties.put("java.naming.factory.initial", "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
            properties.put("java.naming.provider.url", "jnp://localhost:1099");
            properties.put("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs", "org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces");

            InitialContext initialContext=new InitialContext(properties);
            initialContext.rebind("TestRMI", remoteObj);
            System.out.println("server up");

        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(NamingException n)
        {
            n.printStackTrace();
        }
```

```
When i run the client for the 2nd approach it gives error "TestRMI is not bound"
  Client code is:
```

```
    main(){
                        Properties properties=new Properties();
            properties.put("java.naming.factory.initial", "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
            properties.put("java.naming.provider.url", "jnp://localhost:1099");
            properties.put("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs", "org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces");
            InitialContext initialContext=new InitialContext(properties);
            Server server=(Server)PortableRemoteObject.narrow(initialContext.lookup("TestRMI"), Server.class);
    }
```

```
So, i am not able to figure out what is the correct approach for deploying RMI in Jboss. Is it correct to write code in Servlet init method and create a registry.Or we have to use EJB,etc.. If any one have done this before please help me.

Thanks
```

Comment: Do you get that error on (i) the `bind()`? (ii) the `lookup()`? (ii) on invoking the remote method?

Answer (score -1):

You can check if the port 1099 is existing.
May be, the port be tied up already.
Try to appoint a port by:

```
LocateRegistry.createRegistry(port);
```

Comment: I have tried both with createRegistry(port) and getRegistry(). And also i have checked its value,it is getting 1099.

Comment: what exception throw?  this a example:                                server:                                                               reg =  LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);                          reg.bind("TestRMI", c);                                           client:                                                               reg =  LocateRegistry.getRegistry("localhost",1099);
c = (Calculator)reg.lookup("TestRMI");

Comment: It is throwing the same exception.

Comment: That woudln't cause this exception. It would cause a `ConnectException`.